# Error trying to get WSDL SOAP working in Zend

Tags: php, web-services, zend-framework, soap, wsdl

I need to check some data with a web service and I'm doing the call like this:

```
$endpoint = "http://www.telefonicamovistar.com.pe/wsProxyConsultaIf/ServicioProxyConsultaInternetFija.svc?wsdl";


try {

    $opts = array(
        'http' => array(
            'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $client = new \Zend\Soap\Client($endpoint, array('stream_context' => $context,
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 'soapversion' => SOAP_1_1));


    $result = $client->ConsultarClienteFijo(array(
        'CodigoCliente' => '1',
        'CodigoCuenta' => '1',
        'NumeroDocumento' => '41215621',
        'Socio' => 'SI',
        'Telefono' => '2614750',
        'TipoDocumento' => 'DNI',
        'TipoValidacion' => 'D'
    ));
    var_dump($result);
    exit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

With that code I always get 'An unexpected error occurred in the service.' which doesn't give me enough clues to move on.

There's no problem when testing the service through SOAPUI

**EDIT:**

The types of the web service are these:

```
  0 => string 'struct ConsultaClienteRequest {
 string CodigoCliente;
 string CodigoCuenta;
 string NumeroDocumento;
 string Socio;
 string Telefono;
 string TipoDocumento;
 string TipoValidacion;
}' (length=183)

 3 => string 'struct ConsultarClienteFijo {
 ConsultaClienteRequest request;
}
```